# Upgrade Extension from 1.9 to 2.0 - Code Refactoring

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I have my extension developed in CE `1.9.2`. What are the requisites to upgrade it  to `2.0`.

1. Is there any tool available that converts the directory structure of
   1.9 into 2.0 ?
2. If I do it manually, what are the steps involved to convert upgrade
   it to 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lastest Magento 2.x version(2.0.1) ,Add a tool  [Code Migration Toolkit](https://github.com/magento/code-migration) by which ***you can transfer your 3rd party extension  of 1.x  version to 2.x structure***.

- You can Migrate *`Magento 1.x module structure`* to *`Magento 2.0`* structure
  using   Magento client Cli tool ***`bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure`***
- *Migrate Magento 1.x layout.xml Magento 2.0 structure file structure.
  (bin/migrate.php convertLayout*

See the full steps of migration at [Code Migration page](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

So,before migration,**`you should have strong knowledge of Magento 2.X  structure`** Thus you can convert 1.x code to 2.x.You can understand those thing from [code-migration process](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

But honesty ,you need  to do  lot of works for this achieve .